# Getting the right collection format from a JSON

Tags: json, laravel, collections

Currently I get a JSON feedback from Guzzle that I convert into Collections so that it can be used in an @foreach via Blade.
The problem is that I don't get the desired collection form.

In my @foreach I would like to be able to use Laravel's default tagging:

```
@foreach($hostgroups as $hostgroup)
    {{$hostgroup->name }}
@endforeach
```

Here is my current collection:

```
Collection {#215 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    "result" => array:2 [▼
      "Clearcase" => array:1 [▼
        "alias" => "clearcase"
      ]
      "FPGA" => array:1 [▼
        "alias" => "fpga"
      ]
    ]
    "result_code" => 0
  ]
}
```

**My Model**

```php
<?php

namespace App;

class Hostgroup
{
    public static function all() {
        $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
        $hostgroups = $client->get('huri-api.tld', [
            'query' => [
                'action' => 'get_all_hostgroups',
                '_username' => 'user',
                '_secret' => 'secret',
                'output_format' => 'json'
            ]]);
        return collect(json_decode($hostgroups->getBody()->getContents(), true));
    }
}
```

Currently my iterous foreach loop for the values items:

- results
- result_code

Ideally I would like to get a collection of the form:

```
Collection {#215 ▼
    #0 => array:2 [▼
      "name" => "Clearcase",
       "alias" => "clearcase"
      ]
    #1 = > array:2 [▼
      "name" => "fpga",
       "alias" => "fpga"
      ]
    ]
  ]
}
```

Thank's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you can collect only the result:

```php
return collect(json_decode($hostgroups->getBody()->getContents(), true)['result']);
```

Then you can change the way you iterate:

```php
@foreach($hostgroups as $name => $value)
    {{ $name }}
@endforeach
```

**Update**: BTW if you want the format you asked you can use the `map()` function on the `collection`, something like this:

```php
$hostgroups = collect(json_decode($hostgroups->getBody()->getContents(), true)['result']);
return $hostgroups->map(function ($item, $key) {
    $i = [];
    $i['name'] = $key;
    $i['alias'] = $item['alias'];
    return $i;
});
```

Or if you want a `collection` of objects of `stdClass`, so you can access element like in your example `{{$hostgroup->name }}`:

```php
$hostgroups = collect(json_decode($hostgroups->getBody()->getContents(), true)['result']);
return $hostgroups->map(function ($item, $key) {
    $i = new stdClass();
    $i->name = $key;
    $i->alias = $item['alias'];
    return $i;
});
```